# Which algorithm used is by sort function in PHP?

Tags: php

I want to know the algorithm they use to sort an array just for knowledge.
    $arr=array(50,60,40,70,30);
    sort($arr);
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP uses an implementation of [Quicksort.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort).you can try Quicksort.

Answer (score 3):

> Note: Like most PHP sorting functions, sort() uses an implementation of » Quicksort.

Source: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php